# Ajax.BeginForm fade out not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("actionToDo", new AjaxOptions 
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "updatediv",
    OnBegin = "$('#updatediv').fadeOut()", 
    OnComplete = "$('#updatediv').hide().fadeIn()"
}))
{
    <div id='updatediv'>
    </div>
}
```

The fade-in works properly, but the problem is that it won't fade-out when I submit the Ajax request. It just disappears, then fades in the new content. After testing with simple alerts, it seems like the "OnBegin" doesn't happen until *after* the old content has been removed, which contradicts the documentation: "Gets or sets the name of the javascript function to call immediately before the page is updated."

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that when you call fadeout, its too late. Form submission has already occured and that means the div is already gone (due to the nature of the replace method). Keep in mind these events are firing very fast. What you need to do is force the fade out to occur before the form is submitted. There are various solutions to this (many already on stack overflow including using e.preventDefault) but I prefer just hiding the real submit button, adding a fake one and using it to do the fade out, and then triggering a delayed form submit by using a setTimeout. I have also added an outer div to preserve a fixed screen height when the replaced div disappears.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("actionToDo", new AjaxOptions 
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "updatediv",
    OnComplete = "$('#updatediv').hide().fadeIn()"
}))
{
     <div style="height:20px;">
     <div id='updatediv'>
         text to replace</div>
     </div>
    <input id='realsubmit' style='display:none;' type="submit"  />
    <input id='fakesubmit' type="button" value="submit" onclick ="$('#updatediv').fadeOut('slow'); setTimeout(function () { $('#realsubmit').click(); }, 1000);" />
}
```